# Grouping with 2 tables without Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `MOV` and`RENT`

Table structure

```
           RENT
   +----------+------+-----+-----+
   |data      |   C  |  M  |  A  |
   +----------+------+-----+-----+
   |01/01/2020|   1  |  2  |  3  |
   +----------+------+-----+-----+
   |02/01/2020|   2  |  3  |  4  |
   +----------+------+-----+-----+
   |03/01/2020|   3  |  4  |  5  |
   +----------+------+-----+-----+

        MOV
   +---+-------+---------+
   |id | valor |tp_fundo |
   +---+-------+---------+
   |1  |100    |  C      |
   +---+-------+---------+
   |2  |200    |  M      |
   +---+-------+---------+
   |3  |300    |  A      |
   +---+-------+---------+
```

What I need to do is:
Client invested $ 100.00 in investment `C` after 3 days this fund yielded 6% according to the`C` column yield table
So I need to Add up the amount of income on those 3 dates ** (6%) ** and apply on the value of his investment`$ 100 + 6% = $ 6.00`

Here is the select I'm trying to do, but I'm not able to generate the select with:

```
SELECT mov.tipo_fundo,

(mov.valor*(SELECT sum(rf.fundo_conservador) FROM `rentabilidade_fundos` rf where rf.data between
            CASE WHEN ((mov.data_solicitacao) <= (CURRENT_DATE()) ) 
                THEN mov.data_solicitacao
                ELSE (select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day) 
            END                     
            and (select last_day(curdate())) ))/100 as REND_TOTAL_MES_CONSERVADOR,

(mov.valor*(SELECT sum(rf.fundo_moderado) FROM `rentabilidade_fundos` rf where rf.data between
            CASE WHEN ((mov.data_solicitacao) <= (CURRENT_DATE()) ) 
                THEN mov.data_solicitacao
                ELSE (select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day) 
            END                     
            and (select last_day(curdate())) ))/100 as REND_TOTAL_MES_MODERADO,

(mov.valor*(SELECT sum(rf.fundo_arrojado) FROM `rentabilidade_fundos` rf where rf.data between
            CASE WHEN ((mov.data_solicitacao) <= (CURRENT_DATE()) ) 
                THEN mov.data_solicitacao
                ELSE (select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day) 
            END                     
            and 
            (select last_day(curdate())) ))/100 as REND_TOTAL_MES_ARROJADO

from movimentacao mov where 1=1 and mov.tipo_movimento = 'A' and mov.id_usuario=6 GROUP by tipo_fundo
```

Here's how you would need the select to look:

```
   FINAL SELECT

   +---+---------+---------+
   |id |tp_fundo |         |
   +---+---------+---------+
   |1  |C        | $6,00   |
   +---+---------+---------+
   |2  |M        | $18,00  |
   +---+---------+---------+
   |3  |A        | $36,0   |
   +---+---------+---------+
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't realize it was the wrong language, i translated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Fix your schema.

rent should perhaps appear as follows...

```
   +------------+------+------+
   | date       | fund | rent |
   +------------+------+------+
   | 2020/01/01 | c    |    1 |
   | 2020/01/02 | c    |    2 |
   | 2020/01/03 | c    |    3 |
   | 2020/01/01 | m    |    2 |
   | 2020/01/02 | m    |    3 |
   | 2020/01/03 | m    |    4 |
   | 2020/01/01 | a    |    3 |
   | 2020/01/02 | a    |    4 |
   | 2020/01/03 | a    |    5 |
   +------------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select
  m.id,
  m.tp_fundo,
  sum(
    case when m.tp_fundo = 'C' then 0.01 else 0 end * m.valor * r.c +
    case when m.tp_fundo = 'M' then 0.01 else 0 end * m.valor * r.m +
    case when m.tp_fundo = 'A' then 0.01 else 0 end * m.valor * r.a
  ) as total
from mov m
cross join rent r
group by m.id, m.tp_fundo
```

Result:

```
id  tp_fundo  total
--  --------  -----
 1  C             6
 2  M            18
 3  A            36
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vD3aZLeuSmcLfBqgrEFu7P/0).